# How to get the value of max() group when in subquery?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, mysql

So i woud like to find the department name or department id(dpmid) for the group that has the max average of age among the other group and this is my query:

```
select 
 MAX(avg_age) as 'Max average age' FROM (
    SELECT 
      AVG(userage) AS avg_age FROM user_data GROUP BY 
         (select dpmid from department_branch where 
            (select dpmbid from user_department_branch where 
               user_data.userid = user_department_branch.userid)=department_branch.dpmbid)
) AS query1
```

this code show only the max value of average age and when i try to show the name of the group it will show the wrong group name.

So, How to show the name of max group that has subquery from another table???

Comment: Can you publish your table defintions, sample data in each table and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this..

```
select MAX(avg_age) as max_avg, SUBSTRING_INDEX(MAX(avg_age_dep),'##',-1)  as max_age_dep from
(
    SELECT 
     AVG(userage) as avg_age, CONCAT( AVG(userage), CONCAT('##' ,department_name)) as avg_age_dep
     FROM user_data 
     inner join user_department_branch 
            on user_data.userid = user_department_branch.userid
     inner join department_branch 
            on department_branch.dpmbid = user_department_branch.dpmbid
     inner join department
            on department.dpmid = department_branch.dpmid
     group by department_branch.dpmid
) tab_avg_age_by_dep
;
```

I've done some change on ipothesys that the department name is placed in a "department" anagraphical table.. so, as it needed put in join a table in plus, then I changed your query, eventually if the department name is placed (but I don't thing so) in the branch_department table you can add the field and its treatment to your query

**update**

In adjunct to as said, if you wanto to avoid identical average cases you can furtherly make univocal the averages by appending a rownum id in this way:

```
select MAX(avg_age) as max_avg, SUBSTRING_INDEX(MAX(avg_age_dep),'##',-1)  as max_age_dep from
(
    SELECT 
     AVG(userage) as avg_age, CONCAT( AVG(userage), CONCAT('##', CONCAT( @rownum:=@rownum+1, CONCAT('##' ,department_name)))) as avg_age_dep
     FROM user_data 
     inner join user_department_branch 
            on user_data.userid = user_department_branch.userid
     inner join department_branch 
            on department_branch.dpmbid = user_department_branch.dpmbid
     inner join department
            on department.dpmid = department_branch.dpmid
     ,(SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
     group by department_branch.dpmid
) tab_avg_age_by_dep
;
```

Comment: Seems way over complicated.  My solution didn't work for you?  @PuttapornJunlong

Comment: You may add the "concat" part in your sql as you see it in my sql statement and inner join with department table, and "select @rownum" table, but I suggest you to use the last sql statement posted. 

The last version contains a further improvement to avoid that identical averages produce more rows with a wrong department name.. with this last solution you will have, for this case, more rows each of whom has the right department name associated.

Answer (score 0):

I took a shot at what I think you are looking for.  The following will give you the department branch with the highest average age.  I assumed the department_branch table had a department_name field.  You may need an additional join to get the department.

```
SELECT db.department_name, udb.dpmid, AVG(userage) as `Average age`

FROM   user_data as ud

       JOIN user_department_branch as udb
       ON udb.userid = ud.userid

       JOIN department_branch as db
       ON db.dpmbid = udb.dpmbid

GROUP BY udb.dpmid

ORDER BY `Average age` DESC

LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser Tom! I will try to use and improve this solution.